# Firefox Integration with Chrome (Google Accounts)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

Normally I use Chrome or Chromium to browse the web and I love that it keeps all my preferences, history, passwords, bookmarks, extensions and preferences synced across computers using my Google account. Firefox has a similar feature: Sync but it's much more cumbersome to setup.

Sometimes, I would rather prefer starting a browser session in Firefox but the fact that all my data isn't there makes me go back to Chrome. I figured, since these are the two most popular browsers in use, there must exist some hidden feature or extension that would allow Firefox to sync data with Chrome (either directly or via my Google account) and vice-versa. However, I couldn't find anything so far.

Is there a solution to sync my data between Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

Ramhound gave a good answer to this question in a comment:

You can use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) to sync passwords across any supported device and browser. You can then use [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) to sync your bookmarks. You are better off using Google Accounts and Firefox Sync to sync browser specific extensions.

Comment: Please don't delete this.  I'm trying to get the question off of the "unanswered" list.  I marked it "community wiki" and gave credit to the original commenter according to the meta question at http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6822/.